# I'm pretty new to linq lambda. I have a MySQL query.which I need to convert to a lambda query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    s.id, s.[index], s.staffini, 
    MIN(accessdate) AS [In], 
    MAX(accessdate) AS [Out], 
    sa.mode, sa.daytype 
FROM   
    staffattendances AS sa 
INNER JOIN 
    staffs AS s ON sa.staffid = s.id 
GROUP BY 
    staffid, CAST(accessdate AS DATE), s.staffname, 
    sa.mode, sa.daytype, s.[index], s.staffini, s.id
```

How to convert this to a Linq lambda query?

```
var tmp = Context.staffAttendances
                 .Include(t => t.staff)
                 .GroupBy(s => new
                               {
                                   s.StaffId, s., 
                                   s.AccessDate, 
                                   s.staff.StaffName,
                                   s.Mode, s.Daytype,
                                   s.staff.index, s.staff.Id
                               })
                 .Select(x => new staffattdto
                                  {
                                      index = x.Key.index,
                                      StaffIni = x.Key.StaffName,
                                      In = x.Max(t => t.AccessDate),
                                      Out = x.Max(t => t.AccessDate),
                                      mode = x.Key.Mode,
                                      daytype = x.Key.Daytype,
                                  })
                 .OrderByDescending(t => t.In);
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I dont see anythign wrong in your query expect in group by you missed a groupby column on the second line "s.,"

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using `linq query syntax` for these kind of queries.

Sample below:

```
var results = (from o in Organizations
               join m in Members on o.OrganizationId equals m.OrganizationId
               group o by new { o.OrganizationId, m.MemberId } into g
               select new
               {
                    g.Key.OrganizationId,
                    g.Key.MemberId
               })
            .Take(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas you forgot to mention your classes and the relations between the tables, so I have to make a guess.

So you have `Staffs` and `StaffAttendances`. It seems to me that there is a one-to-many relation between `Staffs` and `StaffAttendances`: every `Staff` has zero or more `StaffAttendances`; every `StaffAttendance` belongs to exactly one `Staff`, namely the `Staff` that foreign key `StaffAttendance.StaffId` refers to.

You will have classes similar to the following:

```
class Staff
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Ini {get; set;}
    ...
   
    // Every Staff has zero or more StaffAttendances (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<StaffAttendance> StaffAttendances {get; set;}
}

class StaffAttendance
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Mode {get; set;}
    public int DayType {get; set;}
    ...

    // every StaffAttendance belongs to exactly one Staff, using foreign key
    public int StaffId {get; set;}
    public virtual Staff Staff {get; set;}
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what your query does. It seems something like: "From every Staf, with its zero or more StaffAttendances give me the Id, the StaffName, (maybe some more Staff properties), and from all its StaffAttendances with the same Mode and DayType give me the minimum and maximum StafAttendance AccessDate"

> In entity framework always use Select to query data and select only the properties that you actually plan to use. Only use Include if you plan to change the included data.

The reason for this is that Include will fetch the complete object, inclusive the properties that you won't use. If you have a database with Schools and Students, then every Student will have a foreign key to the School that he attends. Every Student on School [10] will have a foreign key SchoolId with a value [10].

If you use Include to query "School [10] with all its 2000 students" you will be transferring the value 10 more than 2000 times, while you already know this value.

### Use the virtual ICollection

I think your query will be something like:

```
var result = dbContext.Staffs

    // only if you don't want all Staffs:
    .Where(staff => ...)

    .Select(staff => new
    {
        Id = staff.Id,
        Ini = staff.StaffIni,

        Attendance = staff.StaffAttendances.GroupBy(attendance => new
        {
            Mode = attendance.Mode,
            DayType = attendance.DayType,
        },

        // parameter resultSelector, for every [Mode, DayType] combination,
        // and all StaffAttendances that have this [Mode, DayType] combination
        // make one new:
        (modeDayType, staffAttendancesWithThisModeDayType) => new
        {
            Mode = modeDayType.Mode,
            DayType = modeDayType.DayType,

            In = staffAttendancesWithThisModeDayType
                 .Select(staffAttendance => staffAttendance.AccessDate)
                 .Min(),
            Out = staffAttendancesWithThisModeDayType
                 .Select(staffAttendance => staffAttendance.AccessDate)
                 .Max(),
         },
    });
```

Entity framework knows the relations between your tables, and translates the usage of your virtual ICollection into the proper GroupJoin.

It seems to me that you want some more properties. Since I use entity framework my SQL is a bit rusty, but I guess you'll get the gist.

I think that you don't have a Min / Max for DateTime. If you don't, you'll have to convert them to Ticks and back:

```
In = new DateTime(staffAttendancesWithThisModeDayType
                 .Select(staffAttendance => staffAttendance.AccessDate.Ticks)
                 .Min()),
```

If you are using this more often, consider to create an Extension method for this, they are one-liners, and because you reuse them it might save you a lot of time unit testing them:

```
public static DateTime MinAccessDate(this IQueryable<StaffAttendance> attendances)
{
     return attendances.Select(attendance => attendance.AccessDate).Min();
}

public static DateTime Min(this IQueryable<DateTime> dates)
{
    return new DateTime(dates.Select(date => date.Ticks).Min());
}
```

Usage:

```
In = staffAttendancesWithThisModeDayType.MinAccessDate(),
Out = staffAttendancesWithThisModeDayType.MaxAccessDate(),
```

In my opinion, using the virtual ICollection in a one-to-many relationship is the method that is by far the easiest to understand. Unit tests will also be easier, because your input data can come from Dictionaries or Lists instead of from real databases.

### Do the GroupJoin yourself

Some people use a version of entity framework that doesn't understand the virtual ICollection, or they prefer to do the GroupJoin to fetch the Staff with their Attendances themselves. The second halve of the query will be similar:

```
var result = dbContext.Staffs.GroupJoin(dbContext.StaffAttendances,

    staff => staff.Id,                // from every Staff take the primary key
    attendance => attendance.StafId,  // from every StaffAttendance take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector: for every Staff, and its zero or more StaffAttendances
    // make one new
    (staff, attendancesOfThisStaff) => new
    {
        Id = staff.Id,
        Ini = staff.StaffIni,

        Attendance = staff.attendancesOfThisStaff.GroupBy(attendance => new
        {
            Mode = attendance.Mode,
            DayType = attendance.DayType,
        },

        // etc. see above
    });
```